# How can I manipulate XML documents on DOM level from a Visual Studio Code extension?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I would like to [develop a Visual Studio Code extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension), which "formats" [XML documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml) with a specific [XML namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names) opened in Visual Studio Code.

The "formatting" would have to happen on [DOM level](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-DOM/).

How can I write an extension, which does that?

I found https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/11/15/formatters-best-practices, which describes how to format text files in extensions, but this is based on [vscode.TextDocument](https://vscode-api.js.org/interfaces/vscode.TextDocument.html), which does not provide me a DOM.

Further I found https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features and https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide, which gives an idea how to implement language features.

However, none of them shows how to format or refactor code based on an abstract syntax tree or something above, but always "only" on text document level.